# How do I install Sublime Text 2/3?

Tags: software-installation

I installed Sublime Text 2 on 12.04 as per this [tutorial](http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/).

However I don't have adequate permissions when launching the program from the Unity launcher. For example I cannot install packages, or if I add a folder to the sidebar when I close Sublime and reopen, the folder is no longer listed. If I run `sudo sublime` in the terminal all changes remain after closing.

I've tried chown-ing the Sublime Text 2 folder in usr/lib
`sudo chown -R mylogin:mylogin /usr/lib/"Sublime Text 2"` but this seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Install Sublime On Debian/Ubuntu
To install sublime on Debian and Ubuntu, run the following commands.

$ wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
$ echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sublime-text  

#:- https://www.itsmarttricks.com/category/linux-tutorials/

Answer (score 803, accepted):

## Install via the Package Manager(apt-get):

Simply add to your packages:

**For Sublime-Text-2:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

**For Sublime-Text-3:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

## Run Sublime-Text on terminal

```
subl
```

## Install Manually via Terminal:

**Download from the Sublime Site**:

**32-bit:**

```
wget http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2.tar.bz2
tar vxjf Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2.tar.bz2
```

**64-bit:**

```
wget http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2\ x64.tar.bz2
tar vxjf Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2\ x64.tar.bz2
```

**For Both:**

```
sudo mv Sublime\ Text\ 2 /opt/
sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime
```

Source: http://www.tecmint.com/install-sublime-text-editor-in-linux/

## Install Manually via Script:

Check out this nice script on Github("*Install Sublime Text on Fedora.*") that you can run, just make sure to edit the "*.tar.bz2" in the script to download the latest version of Sublime Text!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Usage: {script} [ OPTIONS ] TARGET BUILD
# 
#   TARGET      Default target is "/usr/local".
#   BUILD       If not defined tries to get the build into the Sublime Text 3 website.
# 
# OPTIONS
#
#   -h, --help  Displays this help message.
#
# Report bugs to Henrique Moody <henriquemoody@gmail.com>
#

set -e

if [[ "${1}" = '-h' ]] || [[ "${1}" = '--help' ]]; then
    sed -E 's/^#\s?(.*)/\1/g' "${0}" |
        sed -nE '/^Usage/,/^Report/p' |
        sed "s/{script}/$(basename "${0}")/g"
    exit
fi

declare URL
declare URL_FORMAT="http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/sublime_text_3_build_%d_x%d.tar.bz2"
declare TARGET="${1:-/usr/local}"
declare BUILD="${2}"
declare BITS

if [[ -z "${BUILD}" ]]; then
    BUILD=$(
        curl -Ls http://www.sublimetext.com/3 |
        grep '<h2>Build' |
        head -n1 |
        sed -E 's#<h2>Build ([0-9]+)</h2>#\1#g'
    )
fi

if [[ "$(uname -m)" = "x86_64" ]]; then
    BITS=64
else
    BITS=32
fi

URL=$(printf "${URL_FORMAT}" "${BUILD}" "${BITS}")

read -p "Do you really want to install Sublime Text 3 (Build ${BUILD}, x${BITS}) on \"${TARGET}\"? [Y/n]: " CONFIRM
CONFIRM=$(echo "${CONFIRM}" | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
if [[ "${CONFIRM}" = 'N' ]] || [[ "${CONFIRM}" = 'NO' ]]; then
    echo "Aborted!"
    exit
fi

echo "Downloading Sublime Text 3"
curl -L "${URL}" | tar -xjC ${TARGET}

echo "Creating shortcut file"
cat ${TARGET}/sublime_text_3/sublime_text.desktop |
    sed "s#/opt#${TARGET}#g" |
    cat > "/usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop"

echo "Creating binary file"
cat > ${TARGET}/bin/subl <<SCRIPT
#!/bin/sh
if [ \${1} == \"--help\" ]; then
    ${TARGET}/sublime_text_3/sublime_text --help
else
    ${TARGET}/sublime_text_3/sublime_text \$@ > /dev/null 2>&1 &
fi
SCRIPT

echo "Finish!"
```

Source:
https://gist.github.com/henriquemoody/3288681

This helped me and I hope it helps everyone else as well!

Comment: how can I launch sublime text 2 via the terminal?

Comment: @Vader http://askubuntu.com/questions/354311/launch-sublime-text-2-from-terminal

Comment: Also, to use sublime as your default text editor instead of gedit, you should edit: */usr/share/applications/defaults.list* by putting subl instead gedit.

Comment: worked perfectly in ubuntu 14.04 using the second method `ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3`

Comment: What is ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2? Is it secure and trustworthy? Is there an installation guideline on the main website of the sublime?

Comment: @Sam Very good question. Here is the [ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/sublime-text-3) site and you simply can down it from [sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) directly.

Comment: Worked perfectly with the terminal installation. Just always remember to make the update first. My first attempt failed because I didn't do it.

Comment: It is probably easier to say `sudo mv "Sublime Text 2" /opt/` than `sudo mv Sublime\ Text\ 2 /opt/`. That is, using quotes around the name you don't have to escape the spaces.

Comment: `sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime` .. i'm new to linux. what is ln on this command ? i mean the usability ?

Comment: Now WebUpd8 has stopped maintenance. Sublime Text 3 has official repository (finally).

Comment: To be more specific - it is at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html

Comment: `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.`

Answer (score 67):

Basically, your problem is that you're **using a wrong article** :) If it was on an SE site I would down-vote it.

Manually copying stuff which does not come from Ubuntu repositories into `/usr` is WRONG. This directory is managed by Ubuntu's package manager and messing with it is going to cause you trouble at some point or another - for example, the next time you upgrade your system Sublime will likely be removed without a trace.

Running the program as root is even wronger, especially in the case of SublimeText which has its own package manager which basically downloads stuff from Internet and lets it run on your computer. A simple typo in a plugin could destroy all data on your machine.

A proper solution, if you want to install the program system-wide, would be to find/build a .deb file and install it - this way package manager would be aware of the package. Webupd8 maintains a [PPA for SublimeText2](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/sublime-text-20-stable-released-ppa.html), so you can just use that.

However, there's a much lazier solution which I am personally using - just unpack SublimeText somewhere in your home directory, create a `bin` directory in your home directory and symlink `sublime_text` executable into that directory:

```
mkdir ~/bin
ln -s ~/wherever/sublime/is/sublime_text ~/bin
```

After which you'll be able to run Sublime Text by typing `sublime_text` in the console, from any directory. This does not require root privileges at all and the editor runs just fine.

The article also does some shell integration, such as registering sublime_text as a default editor and adding an icon, and I was too lazy to do that - however, I'm sure that it can be done without messing with system-wide settings.

This does not explain, however, the problems with permissions you're having - SublimeText stores all its settings in your home folder anyway, so even if you installed it system-wide it should not have problems. What probably happened is that you started it the first time with superuser privileges (i.e. from the sudo shell), so the editor's config directory (in `~/.config/sublime-text-2`) is owned by `root` now. You need to do something like

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername /home/yourusername/.config/sublime-text-2
```

to fix this.

Comment: Could you fully explain the bit about creating a bin directory and symlinking it?

Comment: @hellocatfood: I've expanded my answer a bit

Answer (score 21):

Here is how to solve this.

1) undo all the steps in the linked webpage in reverse order.

1a) if you didn't save a copy of your original defaults.list then open a terminal and run

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/defaults.list /usr/share/applications/defaults.list.bak && cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list.bak | sed "s/sublime\.desktop/gedit.desktop/g" | sudo tee /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

2) get the version of sublime you want and extract it to the current directory.

3) in bash `cd` to the directory where you extracted sublime

4) `mv Sublime\ Text\ 2 ~/.local`

4a) if you want to be able to run sublime from the command line then run `mkdir -p ~/bin && ln -s ~/.local/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text ~/bin/sublime`. The default `.bashrc` will add ~/bin to your $PATH the next time your shell launches.

5) Make a file called `sublime.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications/` and paste the following inside.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Sublime Text 2
# Only KDE 4 seems to use GenericName, so we reuse the KDE strings.
# From Ubuntu's language-pack-kde-XX-base packages, version 9.04-20090413.
GenericName=Text Editor

Exec=~/.local/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text
Terminal=false
Icon=~/.local/Sublime Text 2/Icon/48x48/sublime_text.png
Type=Application
Categories=TextEditor;IDE;Development
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=~/.local/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text -n
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

6) `test -e ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list -a 1$(grep -sc \[Default\ Applications\] ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list) != 10  || echo "[Default Applications]" >> ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list; grep gedit.desktop /usr/share/applications/defaults.list | sed "s/gedit\.desktop/sublime.desktop/g" >> ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`

7) done.

It should now be installed locally in your home directory and you should have no more issues with permissions.

Comment: The OP would probably have to delete/chown `~/.config/sublime-text-2` directory as that's what is causing the problem. Anyway, thanks for the detailed instructions.

Comment: Please make a new "How do I install Sublime" question with answer, it would be a nice contribution so that people can do it right instead of following blog posts we can't fix!

Comment: @Sergey Yeah that would probably also work. A big issue with the linked directions though is that they ask you to install something to your /usr/lib manually, which is never good.

Answer (score 7):

You can also also download the Debian package for your particular architecture from
[the sublime website](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

and then run the following;

```
cd download_path
sudo dpkg -i package.deb
```

for example if my download for a 64 bit architecture is in the `Downloads` directory and is called `sublime-text_build-3080_amd64.deb` then  I will run

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3080_amd64.deb
```

In my case it was sublime text 3, you can get for your sublime text 2 also

Answer (score 6):

I think [@Alex L.](https://askubuntu.com/users/74068/alex-l) is completely right.  I recommend never editting your `/usr` fs, add-on commercial software should be installed in either `/opt` for multi-user or `~/opt` for single user (see [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/index.html) especially [`/opt`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html) and [`/home`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/home.html)). Here are just a few more additions to make it *really nice*.

1. You don't have to move your app to `.local` or `/local`; I usually just leave them in `~/opt` (*n.b.*: the tilde is your home directory or `$HOME`).

   ```
   user@machine:~$ cd ~/Downloads
   user@machine:~/Downloads$ cd wget http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime%20Text%202.0.1.tar.bz2
   user@machine:~/Downloads$ cd ..
   user@machine:~$ tar -C ~/opt -xf "~/Downloads/Sublime Text 2"
   ```
2. Make a symlink to sublime_text in `~/bin`, but call it `sublime`; see step 4a in [Alex L.'s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/172755/36961) above.

   ```
   user@machine:~$ ln -s ~/opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text ~/bin/sublime
   ```
3. Same as Alex L.'s step 5, make a file called `sublime.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications/` but add `%f` after `sublime` in the `Exec` field so that you can open it from Nautilus, as described in [this post](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/ubuntu-fix-add-program-to-list-of-applications-in-open-with-when-right-clicking-files-in-nautilus/). Also don't escape spaces for the `Icon` field and use the full path, no tilde. Replace `<user>` with your username.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=Sublime Text 2
   GenericName=Text Editor
   Exec=/home/<user>/bin/sublime %f
   Terminal=false
   Icon=/home/<user>/Sublime Text 2/Icon/48x48/sublime_text.png
   Type=Application
   Categories=Development;IDE;TextEditor
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow

   [NewWindow Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Window
   Exec=/home/<user>/bin/sublime -n
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
4. You shouldn't have to log off, but if it doesn't show up in your dash, right away  maybe you do. Then look for a file to open in Nautilus, right-click and select *Open With Other Applicaton ...* then *Show other applications* button at the bottom, find **Sublime Text 2** in the list, select it and hit *Select*. Your file should open in Sublime Text 2, and from now on for files of that type you will see Sublime Text 2 already listed as an option. You can also set it as the default from Nautilus by right-clicking, selecting *Properties* then *Open With* and finally *Set as default* button after highlighting **Sublime Text 2**. Of course you could have used *Add* to select **Sublime Text 2** to open the file type from the *Properties* window as well.

Comment: Without the full path for the `Exec` key the desktop file will not work in all situations. (though it is true that it will work most of the time).

Comment: Thanks [Alex L.](http://askubuntu.com/users/74068/alex-l)! Very **good** to know! I'm super happy with my sublime-text-2 setup now, and so far everything is working great. Very disappointed that people are being misled by [this post](http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/) :(. However now it seems that there is a ppa provided by [WebUpd8](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/sublime-text-2) that users can install via apt-get :).

Answer (score 5):

Type the following commands in the terminal, for Sublime Text 2 :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

For Sublime Text 3 :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the deb package from the 
   [official site](https://www.sublimetext.com/3).
2. Install the package by `$sudo dpkg -i path_to_the_file.deb`
3. Start the program from `/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text`

Answer (score 4):

Installing [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/) on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

Installing [Sublime text](https://snapcraft.io/sublime-text)

```
sudo snap install sublime-text --classic
```

**Note**: snapd is only works for ubuntu 16.04 or later versions

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Leonard Kakande, you can install it from [official repository](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html). It works for Sublime Text 3 only, though.

Run the following commands in your terminal:

(1) Install the GPG key:

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

(2) Select the channel to use:

***Stable***

```
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

***Dev***

```
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/dev/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

(3) Update apt sources and install Sublime Text

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently made this for your convenience:
https://github.com/TCattd/sublime-text-linux-installer

A Sublime Text 2 and Sublime Text 3 bash script installer. Just download one of the scripts, ST2 or ST2.

For ST2 is: **st2install**

Put ir in your home folder. Then form a terminal (and in the same home folder) run:

```
sudo bash st2install
```

That will take care of all.

You can upgrade with that very same script too, in case a new ST2 version pop out. Same apply for installing/upgrading ST3.

And both versions, using those installers, can live together without conflicts.

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and followed the above provided solutions without success. What did it for me was the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659717/sublime-text-editor-opens-with-no-menu-bar-unless-started-with-sudo).

Essentially:

1. Close all of your sublime app instances
2. Open up the sublime desktop file

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/sublime-text-2.desktop
   ```
3. Edit the file by replacing

   ```
   Exec=/usr/bin/subl %F
   ```

   with

   ```
   Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /usr/bin/subl %F
   ```
4. Delete sublime profile configuration folders

   ```
   rm -fR ~/.config/sublime-text-2
   ```
5. Start sublime from the top menu or shortcut

Comment: While other answers are very interesting, this one really resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install Sublime On Debian/Ubuntu
To install sublime on Debian and Ubuntu, run the following commands.

$ wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https

$ echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list

$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sublime-text

https://www.itsmarttricks.com/category/linux-tutorials/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there has simply something gone wrong during the installation. I'm using Sublime Text 2 on 12.04 and it doesn't need sudo. I suggest you type `sudo apt-get purge sublime-text` in a terminal (depends on which version you've installed. Use the tab key after having typed the line until "subl" twice - each installed version will be displayed).
This will completely remove the installation. After that, go to the homepage of sublime text and make sure you download the .deb package. Browse the package in Nautilus (home folder), right-click on the .deb-package and choose "open with Software Center". In the Software Center, click install and follow the instructions. After that you should be able to launch the application without sudo.

Comment: The instructions he followed don't use deb packages