# How do I update Sublime Text 2?

Tags: text-editor, sublime-text

I have Sublime Text 2 installed and I have it configured to my liking. There is a newer version of Sublime Text 2, but I have put off downloading it since I do not want to lose my configuration.

I was told to just extract the downloaded tar file over the existing files but I am a bit nervous about doing this, since I do not want to lose all of the extensions I have added to Sublime Text nor do I want to lose my configuration, and also I am not sure how to do this.

I have the newer version downloaded and it is in `/var/cache/sublime-text-2/Sublime Text 2 Build 2181.tar.bz2`
I believe my existing Sublime Text 2 editor is in `/usr/lib/sublime-text-2`.

Can anyone give me some direction as to how to extract the latest Sublime Text 2 to be found in `/var/cache/` and ensure that it is extracted to `/usr/lib/sublime-text-2`.
Of course the next question is; can I do this without losing the extensions I have added to Sublime Text 2?

Comment: Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/a/227617/54037

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SublimeText does not store its settings and plugins (at least those you downloaded using PackageControl) in the same directory as the editor itself (`/usr/lib/sublime-text-2` in your case) - the settings are stored in `/home/(yourusername)/.config/sublime-text-2/`, so they won't be overridden when you install a new version.

But, just in case, you can make a backup copy of your current install before unpacking. Something like this would do:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/sublime-text-2 /usr/lib/sublime-text-2.old
sudo tar jxf "/var/cache/sublime-text-2/Sublime Text 2 Build 2181.tar.bz2" /usr/lib
```

Just to note: installing stuff from tarballs into `/usr` is very wrong, if you must use system directories use `/opt` at least. Otherwise SublimeText runs just fine from a location in your home directory. Here I wrote a bit more on the matter: https://askubuntu.com/a/172753/14564

Comment: Thanks Sergey ... I will follow your guidance on installing into my home directory ... thanks again.

Answer (score 17):

How about from PPA? Much easier to install/update I think:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade sub­lime text 3, do the following

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade sublime-text-installer
```