# How to update Sublime Text-3 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: updates, sublime-text

I installed Sublime Text-3,build- 3114 using the .deb package from the [official site](http://www.sublimetext.com/3). I used Sublime Text-3 earlier in Windows.

In Windows, I was able to update within Sublime Text-3 only, but in Ubuntu, there is no such functionality. I have already installed multiple packages and have also customized them, so I don't want to repeat the whole process again.

Is there any way to update Sublime Text-3 in this scenario? And if not, what is the alternative?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/176321/350004

Comment: If you are wondering how to update Sublime, but haven't installed via deb file like the OP, then maybe [`snap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55569627/2126442) is the alternative you're searching for.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Follow the steps given below:

1. Download the latest version of Sublime Text 3 (at this time, it is Build-3126) as a `.deb` package
2. Install GDebi Package Installer (if not installed).
3. Then remove Sublime Text 3 (Build-3114) by opening its `.deb` package(which you downloaded earlier) using GDebi Package Installer and then click on *Remove Package*.
4. Then open the `.deb` package of the latest Sublime Text 3 version (probably, Build-3126) using GDebi Package Installer and click *Install Package* and install Sublime Text 3 Build-3126.

All your configurations (packages installed and other customisations) in Sublime Text 3 which you did earlier will be restored automatically even after following the above procedure. So you need not worry about installing the packages again. You will find those customisations and packages automatically in the latest version you have installed, because updating through this procedure doesn't remove/purge Sublime Text 3 configuration files.

This procedure works also for other code editors like Visual Studio Code and Atom. I have myself tested and verified it.

But you have to install Package Control again.

**EDIT**: Sublime Text 3.0 has been released. To install it in Ubuntu, use `apt` package manager and run the commands given below one-by-one in terminal:

1. Install the GPG key:

   ```
   wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Select the channel to use:

   - **Stable**

     ```
     echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
     ```
   - **Dev**

     ```
     echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/dev/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
     ```
3. Update apt sources and install Sublime Text

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install sublime-text
   ```

Now whenever a Sublime Text update(after Sublime Text 3.0) will be available (depending on the channel you chose while installing Sublime Text), you can update it using Software Updater or by running the commands given below (one-by-one) in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: the Correct answer and the official url source for install sublime text -> https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html

Comment: The last two lines seem to be what's relevant if you have a previous installation. `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 46):

**Update or Install Sublime Text 3 in Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04+.**

1. Check the path of your executable (e.g. `subl`) if you have one (if you know where your installation is e.g. in `/opt/sublime_text` you may skip this step):

```
cat $(which subl)
```

*This will look inside the executable for the installation path.*

*Alternatively you can use a command like `locate sublime_text/` to help you find the installation directory.*

From the [official website](https://www.sublimetext.com/3), the latest version as of editing is build `3211` *(1 October 2019)*.

*The [64-bit tarball](https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3211_x64.tar.bz2) can be downloaded there as well as the [32-bit](https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3211_x32.tar.bz2) one.*

2. Download and untar the file (one command):

```
curl https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3211_x64.tar.bz2 | tar vxj
```

3. Overwrite your old installation e.g.

```
sudo cp -rf sublime_text_3/. /opt/sublime_text/
```

4. Remove the extracted .bz2

```
rm -rf sublime_text_3
```

And you're done!

PS: adding the executable to your path e.g:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text_3/sublime_text /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Frankly speaking just copy and paste these commands in your terminal... and you are done ;-) ;-)  if previously there sublime was absent in your Ubuntu ,it is now there...otherwise now it's updated...
And also maintain the sequence .

Edit: Now, you can install it directly from software center (for 16.04 LTS).

Answer (score 8):

I prefer to use the official channel, so 
**I removed all  unofficial Sublime repos, such as  webupd8team**.
Then 
you should install the GPG key:

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

and add the official channel:

```
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

The last step is

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

(In my case it was OK to do so without previously removing the existed Sublime text version. Now I have the current build number 3143

Links:
sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html
forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-upgrade-to-version-3143-on-ubuntu-16-04/31467

Comment: As it's my 1st answer here , I cannot use more then 2 links in the  answer.  Here are the last 2 links in full form:  https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html
https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-upgrade-to-version-3143-on-ubuntu-16-04/31467

Comment: The best answer. Looks like webupd8team doesn't have the latest at this moment.

Comment: How to remove the unofficial repos?

Answer (score 6):

In case you have Sublime Text Already installed you can just **upgrade**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade sublime-text
```

Hope it helps!