# Unable to start sublime text

Tags: shared-library, sublime-text, idle

I had been using Sublime Text 2 with no issues. 
I installed IDLE and now I'm unable to start Sublime Text. I tried uninstalling IDLE, but Sublime Text is still not starting. Here's the error:

```
Unable to load libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_cairo_create from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_cursor_new_for_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_cursor_unref from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_error_trap_pop from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_error_trap_push from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_input_add from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_input_remove from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_keymap_translate_keyboard_state from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_keyval_to_unicode from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_region_get_rectangles from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_default from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_height from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_rgb_colormap from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_rgba_colormap from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_root_window from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_width from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_n_monitors from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_monitor_geometry from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_unicode_to_keyval from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_get_frame_extents from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_get_origin from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_get_state from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_invalidate_rect from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_set_cursor from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_move_resize from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_get_server_time from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_get_xatom_by_name_for_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_window_set_user_time from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_accel_group_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_accelerator_get_default_mod_mask from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_box_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_box_pack_start from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_new_with_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_set_active from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_clear from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_get from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_set_text from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_set_with_data from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_store from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_wait_for_text from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_container_add from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_container_get_children from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_container_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_container_remove from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_dialog_add_button from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_dialog_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_dialog_run from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_dialog_set_default_response from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_drag_dest_set from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_drag_finish from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_add_filter from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_get_filename from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_get_files from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_current_name from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_do_overwrite_confirmation from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_local_only from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_select_multiple from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_filter_add_pattern from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_filter_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_filter_set_name from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_get_current_event_time from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_im_context_filter_keypress from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_im_context_set_client_window from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_im_multicontext_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_init from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_main from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_main_quit from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_attach_to_widget from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_bar_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_get_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_get_submenu from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_new_with_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_set_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_set_submenu from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_set_use_underline from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_popup from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_shell_append from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_shell_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_message_dialog_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_message_dialog_new_with_markup from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_selection_data_get_uris from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_selection_data_set_text from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_separator_menu_item_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_settings_get_default from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_show_uri from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_vbox_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_add_accelerator from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_add_events from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_destroy from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_display from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_parent from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_screen from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_window from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_grab_focus from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_hide from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_remove_accelerator from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_set_app_paintable from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_set_colormap from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_set_double_buffered from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_set_sensitive from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_show from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_show_all from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_add_accel_group from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_fullscreen from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_iconify from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_maximize from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_move from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_present_with_time from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_remove_accel_group from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_resize from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_default_icon_list from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_default_size from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_keep_above from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_modal from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_position from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_title from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_transient_for from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_type_hint from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_stick from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_unfullscreen from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load cairo_clip from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_create from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_destroy from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_fill from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_font_options_create from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_font_options_destroy from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_font_options_set_antialias from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_get_source from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_image_surface_create from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_image_surface_create_for_data from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_image_surface_get_data from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_image_surface_get_format from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_image_surface_get_height from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_image_surface_get_stride from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_image_surface_get_width from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_line_to from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_matrix_init_scale from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_matrix_init_translate from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_matrix_translate from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_move_to from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_paint_with_alpha from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_pattern_set_extend from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_pattern_set_matrix from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_rectangle from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_reset_clip from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_restore from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_save from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_set_line_width from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_set_operator from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_set_source_rgb from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_set_source_rgba from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_set_source_surface from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_stroke from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_surface_destroy from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_surface_flush from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_translate from libcairo.so
Unable to load cairo_scale from libcairo.so
Unable to load pango_font_description_free from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_font_description_new from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_font_description_set_family from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_font_description_set_size from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_font_description_set_style from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_font_description_set_weight from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_font_get_metrics from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_font_map_load_font from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_font_metrics_get_ascent from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_font_metrics_get_descent from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_font_metrics_unref from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_language_get_default from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_layout_get_context from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_layout_get_pixel_extents from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_layout_set_font_description from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_layout_set_text from libpango-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_cairo_context_set_font_options from libpangocairo-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_cairo_create_layout from libpangocairo-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_font_map_create_context from libpangocairo-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_cairo_font_map_get_default from libpangocairo-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_cairo_show_layout from libpangocairo-1.0.so
Unable to load pango_cairo_update_layout from libpangocairo-1.0.so
Unable to load all required GTK functions
Unable to init px
```

Any solutions?

Comment: You are probably running a x86 version of st2 on a x64 machine or vice-versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Sublime Text 2/3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like sublime is not able to find these libraries

```
libpango-1.0.so libcairo.so libgdk-x11-2.0.so libpangocairo-1.0.so
```

do a locate

```
locate libpango-1.0.so libcairo.so libgdk-x11-2.0.so libpangocairo-1.0.so
```

If somehow these libraries are not present on your system, then install them again. If the error persists even after the install, then create a copy of the installed libraries and rename them to what sublime is expecting.

Comment: how's this usefull? ... so if i have the libraries installed i should destroy my applications only for using sublime ??!?!

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar error but I just had to issue `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0` and all the other dependencies were pulled automatically.

Comment: This is the only thing you need to do to run sublime on Ubuntu server.

Comment: I had the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04. `sudo apt-get install libgtk3.0` solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You installed a version of Sublime Text that does not match the processor architecture of your Ubuntu installation.

There are two downloads available, *Ubuntu 64bit* (also known as amd64) and *Ubuntu 32bit* (also i386). If the output of `uname -a` contains *x86_64* you have a 64bit install of Ubuntu and should use the 64bit package of Sublime Text.

Just download the appropriate package and install it.

Note: The amd64 designation is a bit confusing. If you have a 64bit Intel processor you still use the amd64 packages.

Comment: Sorry for commenting on old post. Thanks for the tip. I got the same exact problem. And now I found out that my version of sublime text editor was i386/32 bit version. Uninstalled it, and reinstalled the 64 bit version and now everything works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: This is the correct answer. The problems happens if you installed the wrong version of ST for your architecture.

Comment: I got this error without installing for the wrong system. @witkacy26's answer fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

In my case trying to run Sublime in a host without X-es gave me that error.

Installing following packages has solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libx11-6 libglib2.0-0  libxft2 libfreetype6 libc6 zlib1g libpng12-0 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross libgcc1
```

(I haven't checked if ALL of them are really needed)

Comment: `libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross` to run Sublime Text? O.o

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer!?

Answer (score 0):

### Background and Short Answer

In my case, after opening a fresh shell instance, running `subl` works as expected. However, after making a number of modifications to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (and/or perhaps another library path environment variable), I suggest that you :

1. clear said variables
2. verify that Sublime now runs
3. narrow down the offending package.

### More Background and Long Answer

I really actually noticed the issue when building a software project that features several external packages: on the first build everything was fine, but subsequent builds would fail when installing MPICH. Because I modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on subsequent builds based on what packages are already installed, the compiler was picking up on a library installed via PETSc rather than the system copy.

If you find yourself in a similar situation, it just might be that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (and/or other environment variables) is initially empty and that you need to set it to certain system paths before modifying it. For example, put `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib"` in your shell profile configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I installed sublime using `snap` and had to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to where snap stored the required shared objects:

```bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/snap/sublime-text/118/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

I ran `locate libgdk-3.so` to discover the path above.