# How to remove Sublime installed using the website instructions?

Tags: software-installation, sublime-text

I installed Sublime following steps from this [Site](http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/). But I read on [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2) that it is wrong way to install. Now my question is how do i remove it.

Comment: What does: sudo sed -i 's/sublime\.desktop/gedit.desktop/g' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
sudo rm -r /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2
sudo rm /usr/bin/sublime
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop
sudo sed -i 's/sublime\.desktop/gedit.desktop/g' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Comment: `sudo sed -i 's/sublime\.desktop/gedit.desktop/g' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list` should do that.

Comment: First of all try: `sudo dpkg -r sublime-text`

Answer (score 1):

Those steps are not wrong, but it would be easier (and sometimes saver as pointed out by your link) to do it using a ppa. So if you still want to remove it then you will have to 'reverse' step 2, 3, 4 and 5 using the following commands.

**Step 2 reverse** `sudo rm -R /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2`

**Step 3 reverse** `sudo rm /usr/bin/sublime`

**Step 4 reverse** `sudo rm /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop`

**Step 5 reverse** `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list` and replace all occurrences of sublime.desktop with gedit.desktop