# Sublime Text 2 broken package

Tags: installation, apt, sublime-text

Whenever I try executing Sublime Text 2 from my terminal by typing `sublime-text`, it give the following:

```
/usr/bin/sublime-text: line 3: /opt/sublime_text_2/sublime_text: No such file or directory
```

Moreover, there are two icons in the menu, none of which work.

These are the following things I tried:

1. Autoremove
2. Reinstallation
3. apt-get upgrade

But none of these seem to work. What should I do?

Comment: How did you install Sublime?

Comment: I'm not sure. I did it a long time back. I probably used `sudo apt-get install`

Comment: You sure wasn't using the PPA? What is the output of `apt-cache sublime*`?

Comment: It says `E: Invalid operation sublime*`

Comment: install sublime 3 type subl problem solved. have good night

Comment: @GOD Fine i'll do that. But how do I remove the two icons that are there on my system?

Comment: just by removing sublime2. try this methods http://askubuntu.com/questions/327747/how-to-remove-sublime-from-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following should work to reinstall Sublime Text 2, and install Sublime Text 3:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /opt/sublime_text_2 /usr/bin/sublime-text
# this will remove the old install directory and execution script
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
# add the ST2 repository
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
# same for ST3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text sublime-text-installer
# install ST2 and ST3, respectively
```

You should now be able to run `sublime-text` from the command line to start ST2, and `subl` to start ST3. As always, please keep in mind the following:

> Sublime Text may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a license **must** be purchased for continued use.