# How can I get rid of a 'dead' icon in search?

Tags: icons, search

So I attempted to install Sublime Text 2 using directions from http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/

However, I messed something up along the way and did not realize that all of the steps did not execute. I attempted to use it when I thought I had finished and saved a file called "designproject1.m" to the desktop. A little while later I tried to reverse the installation steps using [How to remove Sublime installed using the website instructions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327747/how-to-remove-sublime-installed-using-the-website-instructions) As far as I can tell it worked, but when I type 'Sublime' into search (I have since installed ST3) a dead icon comes up before the functioning Sublime Text icon. It does nothing. I cannot read the entire name of it, all that is visible is "~/Desktop/designproject...t 2(UNREGISTERED)".

When I right click on it, the icon changes. I see no options and I have no idea how to get rid of it. Could someone please help me do this?

Photo Album: https://www.flickr.com/photos/130948352@N05/sets/72157650110472817/

Comment: @JasonConti: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime likely copied a file to `~/.local/share/applications/`. Should look at the text files there and see if any of them have `Name=Sublime`, then delete it.

Comment: Going through my "schmucks" answers that didn't get any upvotes...  So finally you got one!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Do a `sudo find / -name "*sublime*.desktop"`

After that copy the path and do a `sudo rm fileNameHereWithPath`