# Sublime Text 2 crashes on startup

Tags: installation, sublime-text

I installed sublime text 2 via apt-get as advised in the numerous answers in this question: [How do I install Sublime Text 2/3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2)

I used the following commands to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

When I start it (using terminal command 'sublime' or the UNITY dock icon, I get the following error:

```
Unable to run package setup:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 165, in upgrade
upgradePackage(pkg, pristinedir, datadir, backupdir)
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 158, in upgradePackage
os.path.join(backupdir, base), inhibitOverwrite)
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 113, in upgradeArchive
shutil.copy(src, dst)
File ".\shutil.py", line 88, in copy
File ".\shutil.py", line 53, in copyfile
IOError: [Errno 13] Keine Berechtigung: u'/home/noel/.config/sublime-text-2/Pristine Packages/Text.sublime-package'
```

"Keine Berechtigung" means "no permission", fyi. ;)

Before installing this via apt-get I had two failed installations (both times the program itself ran fine, but I couldn't save files. Either the error was "couldn't save" or "couldn't save, couldn't create tmp-file").

Can you please help me get this thing finally working? :/

I'm using 13.04, by the way.

EDIT:
I now installed using the script kindly created by henriquemoody (https://gist.github.com/henriquemoody/3288681) and managed to get a working version of sublime running. This question could be considered as answered.

Comment: I followed the one marked as 'accepted' by Jared Burrows. It used concepts known to me and thus appealed to me the most. :)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding you again. :) I edited the question to better reflect the exact way I used for install.

Comment: Could you add the output of `type sublime` and `type sublime-text`?

Comment: Yes. `type sublime` didn't work (`bash: type: sublime: Not found.`) as I removed the symlink. I removed the symlink because it was created by me in the first place during a faulty install attempt.
`type sublime-text` returns `sublime-text is /usr/bin/sublime-text`. Does this help?

Comment: Hey, I installed again with the Gist-script from the afore mentioned answer from the linked question above. It now almost works (gives a small error when starting from terminal, I'll ask the script-creator about that).
Thanks for your help anyway, Braiam (wish I could upvote or somehow give you good Karma ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed again with this script from https://gist.github.com/henriquemoody/3288681. It now almost works (gives a small error when starting from terminal, I'll ask the script-creator about that).

Thanks for helping!