# Launch Sublime Text 2 from terminal

Tags: command-line, sudo, sublime-text, binary

I am new to Ubuntu and is trying to configure my environment so i can launch Sublime Text 2 directly from the terminal. I followed the solution on this post but no luck so far.

**These are steps I did (steps from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196449/installing-sublime-texts-command-line-tool-subl-in-terminal-permission-denie)):**

```
-> cd 
-> mkdir bin
-> sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

In my .bash_profile I added:  `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin`

**This is the error I got:** 
~$ subl --help
No command 'subl' found, did you mean:
 Command 'subs' from package 'libsubtitles-perl' (universe)
 Command 'publ' from package 'atfs' (universe)

**Confusions:** 
First of all, I don't understand why we need to create a bin folder. This folder is now in Home/bin and I don't think I am using it. (I know there are two bin folders. One in File System/usr/bin and the other one File System/usr/local/bin. I am not sure the difference here.)

Second, I noticed  that after I ran the command above (sudo ln -s...) I created a link in my usr/bin folder. However, when I checked this link file, it said the link is broken so i suspect that there is something wrong with the sudo command I executed.

ERROR: *This link cannot be used, because its target "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" doesn't exist.*

This commnad:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

Does /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app indicates the location of my sublime text 2? If yes, then my sublime text is actually in Home/Programs/Sublime Text 2. So should I change the command to `sudo ln -s "/Programs/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl` ?

I already tried this, but since there is already a link file in my usr/bin, I got an error when I tried to run the command above.

ERROR: *ln: failed to create symbolic link `/bin/subl': File exists*  When I attempted to remove it, it said permission denied.

Sorry, I am asking a lot because I am new to Ubuntu. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 31):

Using [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/227617/164891) approach (the ppa one) to install Sublime Text would allow you to open it from the terminal using `subl` or `sublime-text` without the need of additional configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The sublime text you are trying to open looks to be a Mac version. The post you are using shows how to install in Mac OS X. Make sure you have downloaded a version of Sublime for Linux/Ubuntu and try following [this guide](http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/) instead.