# How do I make Sublime Text 3 the default text editor

Tags: text-editor, sublime-text

I'd like to replace gedit, and use Sublime Text 3 as my default text editor for all text files on my Ubuntu system. Can you let me know how do I go about making this change?

Comment: I don't believe this should be a duplicate. One is asking about GUI text editors while the other is asking about CLI text editors.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

### UPDATE

Sublime Text 4 (builds 4000 and higher) has been released, and is the preferred version of Sublime Text to use. There are [instructions](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html) on Sublime's website for installation using the package repositories (`apt`, `pacman`, `yum`, `dnf`, and `zypper`) for a number of popular Linux distributions. However, even installing in this way doesn't automagically make all text/source files open with Sublime, so you'll likely still need to follow the directions below.

These instructions assume that you have installed Sublime Text either using the `.deb` file provided for Debian/Ubuntu-based systems, or using the `apt` repository instructions linked above. If you downloaded the tarball and installed it manually to a location other than `/opt/sublime_text`, you will need to change the paths below to your install location.

---

First, make sure that `/usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop` exists (`sublime-text.desktop` on some systems):

```
ls /usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop
```

Then, open `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` with Sublime:

```
subl /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Search for all instances of `gedit` (`org.gnome.gedit` on some systems) and replace them with `sublime_text`. Save the file, log out and back in, and you should be all set.

---

If for some reason `/usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop` (or `sublime-text.desktop`) doesn't exist, create it:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop
```

Open it in Sublime:

```
subl /usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop
```

and paste the following into it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

However, if you installed Sublime Text using the `.deb` file downloaded from sublimetext.com, the file should already exist.

Comment: This desktop file works great on my system except that the "New Window" or "New File" right click actions cause the mouse cursor to go into a busy-spin mode. Everything seems to work normally though...

Comment: I can not get this to work in Ubuntu 13.10 with Sublime Text 2, I did make sure that sublime_text.desktop was changed to reflect sublime-text-2.desktop, any suggestions?

Comment: btw, its sublime-text not sublime_text, installed from official repo; 14.04

Comment: I can not get this to work in Ubuntu 13.10 with Sublime Text 3, not with `sublime_text` nor `sublime-text`.

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 14.10 & Sublime Text 3. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 with Sublime Text 3 and to make it work I wrote sublime-text (with the dash)

Comment: for some reason I wasnt able to do it on ubuntu 14.10 I was end up installing sublime from Package Manage following the http://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3 
and everything worked out of the box, then I did diff between the desktop files I found some changes

Comment: I got it to work by **1.)** renaming the file in `/usr/share/applications/` from `sublime_text.desktop` to `sublime-text.desktop` and **2.)** removing a duplicate `rm ~/.local/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop`.

Comment: I had to do `sudo subl /usr/share/applications/defaults.list` and change all occurrences of `gedit.desktop` to `sublime-text.desktop`.

Comment: Works fantastic on Ubuntu 20.04.4 thank you!

Comment: if you want a only line solution, you can use: ```sudo sed -i "s/org.gnome.gedit/sublime_text/g" /usr/share/applications/defaults.list```. **UPDATE**: Since Gnome 42 "gedit" was replaced by "TextEditor", so you can update the line with: 
```sudo sed -i "s/org.gnome.TextEditor/sublime_text/g" /usr/share/applications/defaults.list```

Answer (score 0):

By using the following steps you can set Sublime as the default editor- :

1. Just right-click on any text file
2. go to "properties"
3. then go to "open with"
4. select sublime-text from the lists of applications
5. the click on "set as default" tab.

Now your default browser is sublime-text. You can set any app as your default browser by following above method.

Comment: I've been doing that, I was hoping to find out if there were a system wide change I could make for all text files.

Comment: I thought that that would change it for all of the txt's... maybe I'm wrong, but I was pretty sure...

Comment: If it's missing from the list, apply the changes mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/a/755041/80283