# How to change display app for sh scripts?

Tags: nautilus, file-association

If I double click on `sh` script in Nautilus and choose *Display*, it opens it in the Emacs.

I want to change into Sublime Text 3, by adding to the `mimeapps.list`:

```
text/x-shellscript=sublime_text.desktop
```

But it didn't help. How can I change the *display* app for this?

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer in this post:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/396938/how-do-i-make-sublime-text-3-the-default-text-editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to set `application/x-shellscript`, not the `text` one, as `file --mime` suggests.