# Sublime installation error

Tags: software-installation, sublime-text

I am trying to install Sublime through the following command. But it returns error.

```
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-2
```

but it returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sublime-text-2
```

Any helps I have not found any similar question and solution for this problem.

And Also 2 is the recent one or version 3 is available.

Comment: i showed error.   its not duplicate  , see  i tried those steps and getting the error. That's y i am posted a question.

Comment: It's `sudo apt-get install sublime-text` not `sudo apt-get install sublime-text-2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the ppa and install as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Comment: still i am getting the same error.  Is it any package missing in my installed Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be installing [Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext.com/3), not ST2, as it is much more up-to-date with many bug fixes and added features. On the page I linked, select either Ubuntu 64-bit or 32-bit, depending on your system, and save the `.deb` file to your `~/Downloads` directory. Next, run the following commands, where `XXXX` is the build number:

```sh
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-XXXX_amd64.deb 
# for 64-bit
# or
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-XXXX_i386.deb 
# for 32-bit
```

This will install ST3 in `/opt/sublime_text`, put the `subl` command in `/usr/bin/subl`, and set up icons properly. You can then follow my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/397387/169120) on making Sublime the default text editor.