# Disable “A new version of Sublime Text is available, download now?” in Sublime 3 (stable channel)

Tags: updates, sublime-text

I am using package manager to handle updates without manual reinstallation.

I installed Sublime as recommended in [How do I install Sublime Text 2/3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3) with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

My user settings, after change recommended in https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/disable-update-available-pop-up/1381 are following:

```
{
"font_size": 11,
"ignored_packages":
[
"Vintage"
],
"tab_size": 3,
"update_check": false
}
```

Despite this on every Sublime Text start I am attacked by "A new version of Sublime Text is available, download now?"

How can I get rid of this obnoxious popup?

I know that it goes away after ppa is updated and I apply upgrade - but after every release I have about week of pointless, unremovable message spam.

Comment: an issue has been logged on the official ST3 bug tracker - https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1206 - so I would recommend subscribing to it to be notified when it gets fixed

Comment: many web pages and documentation pages on the official site are outdated or just plain wrong, unfortunately.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny Jon Skinner is in no way hostile to the bug tracker - he actually refers to it somewhat often, according to Will Bond (wbond), one of the originators of the bug tracker and now an official Sublime core developer. A lot of old topics got deleted when the Sublime forum was ported from PHPBB to [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/) for some reason. However, the bug tracker *is* still "unofficial", just like the unofficial docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1206#issuecomment-221630273 this is one of functions that is removed from evaluation version of Sublime Text.

```js
"update_check": false
```

in user settings has no effect in an unpaid version.

[image]

What makes sense I guess, if you use Sublime long enough to be bothered by this: you are not evaluating it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Set `"update_check": false` in user settings has no any effects in an unpaid version. Instead, I just take a easy way by adding a hosts rule `127.0.0.0 www.sublimetext.com` in /etc/hosts file. But take care, when you want to install some packages, you may remove this rule temporarily.

Comment: For me blocking access to `www.sublimetext.com` with hosts file failed to block notifications. Are you sure that it actually works?

Comment: This actually works, thanks! Make sure to add both `127.0.0.0 sublimehq.com` and `127.0.0.0 sublimehq.com` to silence this annoying popup. I also added `127.0.0.0 license.sublimehq.com` because why not?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable workaround.

Comment: For Windows users add rules to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773139/disable-a-new-version-of-sublime-text-is-available-download-now-in-sublime-3/773375#comment1155389_773139) in the comments, the `"update_check"` setting has been ignored since about Build 3080. If it was working, setting

```js
"update_check": false
```

in your user settings should disable the popup you are seeing. Unfortunately, that's not happening currently. You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1206) in the unofficial Sublime Text bug tracker to see if it gets resolved.

---

Due to the relatively rapid pace of development at this time, instead of relying on the unofficial PPA, I would recommend instead installing from the Ubuntu `.deb` files located on [sublimetext.com/3](https://sublimetext.com/3). See my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/707904/169120) for simple instructions on how to do that. Basically, when the new version popup appears, click on the <kbd>Upgrade</kbd> button, which will take you to the download page. Click on Ubuntu 64-bit or Ubuntu 32-bit, depending on your system, and save the `.deb` to your Downloads folder. In the terminal, enter the following commands, where `XXXX` is the build number:

```sh
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-XXXX_amd_64.deb
# or sublime-text_build-XXXX_i386.deb for 32-bit
```

And that's it. Sublime is installed into `/opt/sublime_text`, and the `subl` shortcut is placed in `/usr/bin`. It will use the same config directory as the PPA version. If you wish to use `sublime` instead of `subl`, run this:

```sh
sudo rm /usr/bin/sublime
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/subl /usr/bin/sublime
```

Please note that if you are a registered user (and you should be if you use Sublime professionally, or for an extended length of time; it's not freeware), you can use the [dev builds](https://sublimetext.com/3dev), which contain more bleeding-edge features, and are updated much more frequently. These builds are only available via `.deb`.

Comment: I know that it is possible to upgrade ST manually after every update. As I mentioned I want to avoid it. In fact, as mentioned I found a way to upgrade ST together with other programs, using standard Linux method for that (package manager). I am not interested in dev builds - ST never had improvements that I noticed and I am not willing to be an unpaid tester of commercial software. I want to find workaround for ST bug.