# Ubuntu 16.04 does not recognize sublime as a text editor

Tags: 16.04, sublime-text

I've installed it, I can run it via the terminal, I also can find it via search (comes up as untitled - Sublime Text) and lock it to the launcher, but when I right click a file and try to choose sublime as the application it's not in the list. I've tried setting it as default via the instructions given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396938/how-do-i-make-sublime-text-3-the-default-text-editor) , but that didn't help. I've set it as the default editor for git commits, but that doesn't work either. I've checked that it's in the path: subl sits in /usr/bin and `echo $PATH` returns:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Anyone having the same issue?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732464/sublime-text-not-showing-in-nautilus-open-with-menu) solution?