# Getting Sublime Text 3 listed as an available application [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: 16.04, configuration, sublime-text

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and have installed Sublime Text 3 via a .deb file. I can open the program easily enough and can open files from within it, but I can't seem to find an option to make Sublime Text 3 the default program for any text file that I try to open in the GUI.

I've already tried using the option of right-clicking, selecting 'open with' and then trying to use 'other application' other than the suggested ones. Sublime Text isn't showing up as an option.

I've also tried using Ubuntu Tweak but even it's File Type Manager option doesn't give Sublime Text as an option.

I think there has to be a setting somewhere that I can use to make Sublime Text be associated with editor options, but my googling hasn't brought that out.

Any suggestions?

EDIT! Solved. I found my answer over at [this post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732464/sublime-text-not-showing-in-nautilus-open-with-menu) Worked like a charm!

Comment: do you get anything different if you right click and go to "properties" and then choose "open with"?

Comment: That's the functionality that isn't working. 'open with' doesn't do anything differently from the Properties menu. What I'm thinking is that the Sublime Text program itself isn't being seen by Ubuntu as a viable program to open things with.

The thing is I actually fixed this before by editing a config file, but I forgot which one and can't find the web page that gave me the lesson...

Comment: I found my answer over at [this post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732464/sublime-text-not-showing-in-nautilus-open-with-menu) Worked like a charm!