# Sublime Text build 3103 fails

Tags: 15.04, software-center, sublime-text

I downloaded sublime-text_build-3103_amd64.deb, but it says it demages the available package "sublime-text-installer" because of conflict with sublime-text() when I open it in the software center. This error msg is shown inside ubuntu software center.

What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently originally installed Sublime Text from a third-party source or PPD. On the command line, run

```
sudo apt-get remove sublime-text-installer
```

to remove the old package, then switch to the directory where you downloaded the new `.deb` file and run

```
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3103_amd64.deb
```

to reinstall from the official source. This method will **not** remove your custom settings or packages. However, depending on how you set up your previous installation, you'll need to use the command-line shortcut `subl` instead of `sublime`.

Finally, I recommend reading through my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396938/how-do-i-make-sublime-text-3-the-default-text-editor/397387#397387) for information on making Sublime your default text editor, if you haven't already.

Comment: Cheers, Mattman.