# Unable to make Sublime Text-2 as my default app

Tags: 16.04, text-editor, sublime-text

I tried to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396938/how-do-i-make-sublime-text-3-the-default-text-editor) to make sublime text 2 as my default text editor

First I did

```
ls /usr/share/applications
```

Here I found out that the name was

```
sublime-text-2.desktop
```

Then I opened

```
subl /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

and then replaced all instances of gedit to sublime-text-2 parallel to what is explained in the link and then logged out and back in,

But it does nothing..

I have also tried replacing gedit with subl but to no avail please help

I have Ubuntu 16 dual booted on my system

NOTE: when I run sublime from terminal using

```
subl
```

then it works but sometimes shows errors like the following:

```
GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 3666 was not found when attempting to remove it
```