# Sublime text as default editor for all text files

Tags: text-editor, sublime-text

I have seen other [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396938/how-do-i-make-sublime-text-3-the-default-text-editor), but after following instructions my default editor is LibreOffice, even for txt files.

I want to have Sublime Text 3 as default editor for all text related files: txt, makefile, cpp, h, md, etc.

My [default list](https://www.dropbox.com/s/22cpp7orsf03et2/defaults.list?dl=0) is full of sublime-text.desktop, and does not contain any libreoffice-writer.desktop. However, all txt files are opened in LibreOffice Writer. The only extension that is opened in sublime text after double clicking is cpp. I can open sublime-text as usual (and also via subl in command line) and can open files from it, but I want to open text files in Sublime Text by double clicking on them. The version of Sublime Text is 3126. Ubuntu is 16.04.

Here is [sublime-text.desktop](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6u6ululfqar12fc/sublime_text.desktop?dl=0) and here is [defaults.list](https://www.dropbox.com/s/22cpp7orsf03et2/defaults.list?dl=0).

How can I set sublime text as default editor and why LibreOffice writer opens text files?

Comment: I don't have a dropbox-account, this might be the reason why I can't see much in your provided links. Other users may have the same problem.

Comment: I fixed links so that you can see directly text files. No need for dropbox account to see the files.

Comment: Create an empty `file.txt`, right-click > Properties > Open with > *Select Sublime* > Set as default - Is any `.txt` opened with Sublime now?

Comment: Confusion with dash and underscore? In `default.list.txt` the entries point to `sublime-text.desktop` in some cases and to `sublime_text.desktop`in other cases.

Comment: Amazing spot @mook765! It was sublime-text.desktop on some entries even though it should've been sublime_text.desktop. Now solved.

Comment: Great. Would be nice if you put this in an answer then. I will come and upvote.

Answer (score 11):

The solution provided by Anwesha will work but you will have to manually make sublime text your default opening application for all file formats.

What worked for me in 17.10 was using `update-alternatives`

First what you need is the path to the executable file for sublime text. I have ST 3 and it was at `/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text`

Then open your terminal and use the following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor gnome-text-editor /path/to/executablesublime 100
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-text-editor
```

This will bring up a list of the available alternatives, where the default is marked by an asterisk. If sublime text is not it, then select it now by entering corresponding number. Make sure sublime-text's priority is the highest.

And you're done! Hope this helps :D

Comment: in addition to this, i also had to edit _/usr/share/applications/defaults.list_, to remove `text/plain=gedit.desktop`, for the `gnome-text-editor` setting to take effect for simple text files. same for other mime types for which you want the default text editor to apply, for example `text/x-python=gedit.desktop`

Comment: Please add the comment to the answer itself. It would be much more helpful

Answer (score 9):

To make *Sublime Text* your default text editor,
you need to right-click on any text file,
select **Properties**, then the **Open With** tab.
Select ***Sublime*** from the list,
and click on the **Set as default** Button.

Comment: Seriously? those are Wimdows settings...

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and I can confirm that Right click => Properties gives access to a "Open With" tab that allows to change the default opening application