# How do I lauch sublime text 2 on ubuntu 12?

Tags: installation, sublime-text

I just downloaded sublime text via this method [How do I install Sublime Text 2/3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Now I want to launch it (just simple gui launch for now) to make sure it is installed. I see it in the history in the software center. But when I search in the software center under sublime-text I don't see it.

How do I launch the program? I am new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Three ways.

way 1: Just to confirm finally that its installed to Ubuntu with dpkg

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep sublime-text
```

way 2: Open your terminal and type as

```
      sublime-text
```

it will open that.

way 3: Type as sublime-text in your Unity dash and you can open it.