# What editors are available for writing CoffeeScript?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a good editor for [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). What I want is syntax highlighting and auto indentation when a new line is entered, like [IDLE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html) for Python.

I've already tried the [gedit-coffeescript](https://github.com/wavded/gedit-coffeescript) plugin, but it does only syntax highlighting not the indentation formatting. I have not tried [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), as I'm not comfortable with it.

I hope someone would know a good editor for writing [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/).

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084167/ide-or-its-add-in-for-coffeescript-programming). Also, would this question be "too broad"?

Comment: No it will not be too broad.. I hardly find any good editor and also after 20 hours of my post, I didn't get any good one.

Answer (score 2):

### [CoffeeScript plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39007/coffeescript-netbeans) for [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)

There is a CoffeeScript [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39007/coffeescript-netbeans) for [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/), which should do what you want.

From the [plugin page](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39007/coffeescript-netbeans):

> CoffeeScript editor features:
>
> - Just works!
>
>   - (No need for Node.js)
> - Advanced syntax highlighting
> - Error checking by background compilation
>
>   - (Rhino JavaScript engine is used to compile *.coffee files)
> - Autocompiling to a JavaScript file in the same directory
>
>   - (Test it in a web browser right away)
> - Syntax highlighting and error checking in scripts
>
>   - (HTML and PHP files)
> - Indentation & formatting, code folding
> - Option to use Node.js with [coffee](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#installation) command for compiling. Supported platforms: Mac, Linux and new experimental support for
>   Windows.
> - Cakefile project support

To install it, first you should install NetBeans:

1. Navigate to the [download page.](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html).
2. Download the Java SE version.
3. Make the downloaded file executable.
4. Run the downloaded file and install by following the instructions.
5. Run *NetBeans*.
6. Install the "CoffeeScript Netbeans" plugin from **Tools** → **Plugins**.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. :) It would be good to get any light weight editor like IDLE. Definitely it will help others too. I'm sure you will revert with your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use sublime text editor, thats having Both **synatx highlighting** and as well as **auto indentation** also. you no need to use space.

[Read this , you will get clear idea.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/06/installing-sublime-text-in-ubuntu)

[How do I install Sublime Text 2/3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2)

Hope that helps.

Comment: You should mention that it's a paid for program, with free evaluation.

Comment: @minerz029 yes it is paid but you can work with the unregistered copy without any problem. It only ask you to buy time to time but never stops working with all its features.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It would be good to point out the basics steps here, how to install it in Ubuntu. :)

Comment: @SauravKumar we have huge answers for installing from our home site. please look my answer for the installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest geany as it still an editor, not a huge IDE. It has syntax highlighting and auto indentation. And it is present in a standard ubuntu repo.

Comment: Links to install, feature lists and a screenshot would be nice.

Comment: Really? apt-get is the link to install and google image search for 'geany' will give you screenshots. May I please install and use it instead of you on your PC?

Comment: Geany doesn't highlight CoffeeScript, sorry.