# Ubuntu Can't Run Sublime Text 2 executable

Tags: sublime-text

I've installed Sublime Text 2 on my Ubuntu linux VM. The executable appears to be in `/opt/sublime_text_2`.

When I click on sublime_text executable it opens a new terminal window and does not open sublime text.

If I enter from the terminal: `/opt/sublime_text_2/sublime_text` a new terminal window pops up with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/sublime_text_2/sublime_text --class=sublime-text-2 "$@"
```

and Sublime Text does not open

Comment: How did you install it? Anyway, I would add this as an answer, but after [installing Sublime Text 2](http://askubuntu.com/a/227617/1785960), I was able to open it just by running `sublime-text`.

Comment: Have you tried running it from the dash? Seems like you installed it from their website.

Comment: you could use sublime text 3, it's available in a deb package

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest re-installing Sublime Text from scratch. I highly recommend using Sublime Text 3, as it has many new features and bug fixes that aren't in ST2, and many plugins available through [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net) are moving to ST3-only versions to take advantage of the additional features. Also, ST3 is available as a `.deb` for Ubuntu, making installation a 1-step process.

To install ST3, go to [the download page](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) and select `Ubuntu 64-bit` or `Ubuntu 32-bit`, depending on your system. After downloading, go to your Downloads directory in your terminal and run

```
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3059_amd64.deb
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3059_i386.deb
```

depending on the version you downloaded. It will install everything in `/opt/sublime_text`, will place a `sublime_text.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` (and put an icon in the Unity launcher, IIRC), and will also create `/usr/bin/subl` for starting Sublime from the command line.

---

If for some reason you absolutely need to use ST2, then reinstall by following these steps:

1. run `sudo rm -r /opt/sublime_text_2` to remove the old directory.
2. Go to http://www.sublimetext.com/2 and download either the `Linux 32-bit` or `Linux 64-bit` file, depending on your system.
3. In your terminal, determine the name of the file you downloaded (either `Sublime Text 2.0.2.tar.bz2` or `Sublime Text 2.0.2x64.tar.bz2`) and run

   ```
   tar jxvf "Sublime Text 2...tar.bz2"
   ```

   to unpack the archive and create a directory named `Sublime Text 2`.
4. Run

   ```
   sudo mv "Sublime Text 2" /opt/sublime_text_2
   ```

   to move the directory to the proper location and rename it to something without spaces.
5. Double-check that `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH` by running

   ```
   echo $PATH
   ```

   then create a `subl` shortcut by running

   ```
   sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text_2/sublime_text /usr/local/bin/subl
   ```

You should now be able to start Sublime correctly from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

How did you installed Sublime Text 2?

Try to do a link of the binary to the /usr/bin:

```
sudo ln -sf /opt/sublime_text2/bin/sublime_text2 /usr/bin/
```

Then launch Sublime Text from the terminal as your normal user, and see if it shows any errors:

```
$ sublime_text2
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it was calling sublime text 2.  I though it was opening up a new terminal, but actually it was in fact Sublime Text 2 with the bin script.  Sorry!