# Remove "(UNREGISTRED)" string from window title of Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text

I've installed Sublime Text 2 using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/227617/258266) and is working fine.

My problem is this annoying string `(UNREGISTRED)` from the window title. Is there any way to remove it / change it?

Comment: I wonder who is more annoyed, the developer who built and maintains Sublime Text + grants very generous evaluation terms for a paid product, or a user seeing a few extra characters in their window title?

Comment: I found this question because my fully legit copy of Sublime has started displaying the (UNREGISTERED) message. I've even removed and re-added the license key.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

https://www.sublimetext.com/buy

> Sublime Text may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a license must be purchased for continued use.
>
> Licenses are per-user, rather than per-machine, so you can enjoy Sublime Text on as many computers and operating systems as you wish with your license

---

> **Alternative Payment Methods**
>
> PayPal is currently the only way to purchase a license for Sublime Text. However, for most countries a PayPal account is not required; you can purchase as a guest using a credit card. Unfortunately, PayPal requires users in some countries, such as New Zealand, to create an account.
>
> PayPal sometimes rejects valid credit cards. If this occurs, trying again later or using an alternate credit card has helped many customers.

Getting rid of the "unregistered" text will cost you 70 USD.

---

This is not software from Ubuntu itself. This is [third party software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-party_software_component) and the creator of this software is free to choose their license. In this case it costs money.

Comment: Hmmm... Pay?!? I thought Ubuntu software is free... I don't have any money :(

Comment: @user258266 - Sublime Text is not part of the Ubuntu distribution. PPAs are "Personal Package Archives" set up by individuals to redistribute software. Much of it is free, some is not, like Sublime. It is up to you to understand and comply with the licenses for each piece of software you use. Just because the base Ubuntu distribution is freely distributable (although you can pay for it if you want to) does not mean that all software that runs on it is free. Many examples are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proprietary_software_for_Linux).

Comment: now is 80 USD...

Comment: Worth every penny.  Not only can you use it on any Win/Mac/Linux computer you work on, your personal license of Sublime Text allows you to use it on your computer at work.  See https://www.sublimetext.com/sales_faq  Being able to edit remote server files locally using Sublime (without sshfs) is reason enough in my opinion.  See https://data36.com/sublime-text-data-science-remote-server/ for more info.

Answer (score 13):

Go to Preferences -> Settings - User and add

```
"update_check": false
```

to the file. This is made to disable automatic updates, but it also appears to disable the notification, at least for me.

While purchasing a legitimate copy is highly recommended, it is still the user's choice and not particularly a topic for this question.

Comment: But this doesn't remove the *“(UNREGISTERED)”* string from the window title only the notification.

Comment: It doesn't working anymore.