# cannot make sublime text 3 work on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, 64-bit, sublime-text

Downloaded different versions and from different places, still cannot get it work on 14.04. I could get it to run successfully on OS X and Ubuntu 12.04.

```
drwxrwxrwx  5 root    root       4096 Sep  5 17:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 root    root       4096 Aug 19 17:39 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root       4096 Aug 26 20:51 opt/
drwxrwxr-x  4 achippa achippa    4096 Aug 26 20:50 sublime_text_3/
-rw-r--r--  1 achippa achippa 7557246 Sep  5 17:14 sublime_text_3_build_3065_x64.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r--  1 achippa achippa 6369566 Sep  5 16:53 sublime-text_build-3065_i386.deb
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    root       4096 Aug 26 20:51 usr/
achippa@ubuntu:/usr/local/src$ cd sublime_text_3/
achippa@ubuntu:/usr/local/src/sublime_text_3$ ./sublime_text 
-bash: ./sublime_text: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
achippa@ubuntu:/usr/local/src/sublime_text_3$ /usr/local/bin/subl
Unable to load libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_cairo_create from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_cursor_new_for_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_cursor_unref from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
...
```

With i386.deb I see a bunch of `unable to load...` errors. With x64_tar.bz2, I see an `Exec format error`. Which is the right file to download for 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: [How do I install Sublime Text 2/3?](http://askubuntu.com/q/172698/22949) (particularly [the accepted answer there](http://askubuntu.com/a/227617/22949)) should work. But if you don't want to do it that way, then you should [edit] your question with the complete and exact output of your attempt to install using `sublime-text_build-3065_i386.deb` *and/or* say if there is 64-bit .deb file available that you're willing to use.

Answer (score -2):

you'd better check your OS and the sublime deb package (or bz2) file are matched. I unzip the 64 bits sublime bz2 package into my home directory, and go the same "Exec format error" when I try to start sublime_text, and my os is 32 bits version of Ubuntu 14.10.

If you try to install the deb package is not match the OS architecture, it will report error message and you could not install that.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Unfortunately this does not appear to answer what the OP is really asking. They have already attempted to install Sublime Text from both the 32-bit (i386) and 64-bit (amd64) packages. You are correct that "exec format error" suggests their system is 32-bit, but they've already tried your advice of attempting to install with the 32-bit package.