# sudo: sublime: command not found

Tags: sublime-text

I performed all the steps to install sublime 2 on my Ubuntu 14.04 as shown in this link... [askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3)

but when I try to perform this command

```
sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime
```

it gives me an output

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/sublime’: File exists
```

and when I try to add Sublime Text to the Unity luncher using this command

```
sudo sublime /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop
```

it gives me an output

```
sudo: sublime: command not found
```

Please help me soon. Thank you.

Comment: The command to start Sublime is `subl`. To your first error: Maybe you already created a file `/usr/bin/sublime`, but it isn't executable.

Comment: Well thanks for answer. But it didn't help me though. And you are right it isn't executable file. Please guide me.

Comment: Make the file executable using `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/sublime` Then you should be able to just run `sublime` to start it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `/usr/bin/sublime` already exists, but there is some issue with it, let's get rid of it first:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/sublime
```

Next, we'll create the symlink again:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime
```

Finally, we'll clear the path cache just in case:

```
hash -r
```

You should now be able to run

```
sublime filename
```

or

```
sudo sublime filename
```

without issues.

Comment: It is working bro....but shell giving me some error like ...........GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 3212 was not found when attempting to remove it...please help me to find cure for it, thank you.

Comment: @santabanta see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23166118/1426065) to a similar question on Stack Overflow for an explanation. Essentially, as long as nothing is crashing, it's no big deal.

Answer (score 3):

use subl command instead of sublime