# Why does Sublime from terminal open two windows?

Tags: sublime-text

I want to be able to open dir in sublime from terminal.

Whenever I do `subl .`  it opens current dir in 2 sublime editors. 
Of course I need it to open only one.

My assumption is that I've messed with symlinks, but I might be wrong.

Comment: What is `subl`? How did you installed sublime?

Comment: I've gone trough couple of aticles - one of them I believe is http://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3,  but along the way I might have done smtn like   `sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime` or similar...  I believe subl is a symlink for  sublime  - that I've install a long ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't messed up with symlinks, sublime has installed correctly. That is actually the right behavior.

The reason why does it open two sublime instances (my bet):

- There was a project already opened or
- You didn't closed the previous files opened

In either case you may want to:

- Close any project (Project -> Close Project) or
- Close all the files (File -> Close All Files)

Comment: `Project -> Remove all folders from Project`  did it. Thank you.

Comment: This solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29236116/755405

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `-a` flag to the subl command causes files to "open in current window", which prevents subsequent windows opening.

```
alias subl='subl -a'
```