# Vagrant/VirtualBox - how to run GUI program from within VM

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I successfully instead VirtualBox and Vagrant and have a trusty32 Ubuntu instance running inside a VirtualBox VM on my Windows 7 machine.

However, now I am at a conceptual roadblock whereby I don't quite understand how I run a GUI program from inside the VM.

I want to get a development environment running on the VM - either SublimeText or Webstorm. But how do I run those programs from within the VM?

I don't get it.

Comment: You may have installed the trusty32 server instead of the desktop version. You'll want to make sure you are using the right version. Then worry about installing the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to Ubuntu when you mean

> "how do I run those programs from within the VM"

In that case, check the link [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3) for the steps to install Sublime Text through Terminal. If this doesn't answer your question, kindly brief what I have missed.

Comment: hmmm, but I suppose I have to install gnome or xfce first before I can use sublimetext within the Ubuntu VM. I was hoping there was a way around that...

Comment: Not necessarily. Gnome or Xfce are desktop environment for Ubuntu. Just like a theme for Ubuntu which changes the GUI (Icons,fonts and appearance). You can install Sublime Text without Gnome or Xfce.