# Running Sublime 2 from the launcher opens Sublime 1 version

Tags: launcher

I previously had Sublime 1 installed on my system. I subsequently installed Sublime 2. I unpinned Sublime 1 from the launcher, opened Sublime 2, and pinned it to the launcher. However, when I run Sublime 2 from the launcher, Sublime 1 runs instead. How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing Sublime 1?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem installing sublime through the command terminal [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3).