# Sublime text starts with "sudo sublime" but not "sublime"

Tags: python, sublime-text

If I start sublime-text with

```
sudo sublime
```

I see package control and can access packages.

If I start sublime-text with

```
sublime
```

Output of ls -la on directory:

```
ls -la /opt/sublime_text
insgesamt 11980
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    4096 Aug 20 16:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root    4096 Aug 20 16:17 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   20504 Aug 17 21:56 changelog.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  189552 Aug 17 21:56 crash_reporter
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root    4096 Aug 17 21:56 Icon
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Aug 17 21:56 Packages
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4271136 Aug 17 21:56 plugin_host
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2649206 Aug 17 21:56 python3.3.zip
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    4096 Aug 20 16:30 Rainbowth
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   19351 Aug 17 21:56 sublime_plugin.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   32202 Aug 17 21:56 sublime.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5046304 Aug 17 21:56 sublime_text
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     532 Aug 17 21:56 sublime_text.desktop
```

I can't. Why is that?

Sublime-text has been installed in opt/sublime_text where I can't write to by default.

Comment: which method did you follow to install sublime? and what does `ls -la /opt/sublime_text` say

Comment: Output above. I guess I ussed this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3 that is the cmd command in the first post.

Comment: if you followed 'download from sublime site" in that link, do `sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime`.

Comment: I used this: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer` I'm using sublime text 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a symbolic link to use at the command line:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime
```

Now, change the ownership of `/usr/bin/sublime` and `~/.config/sublime-text-3` from `root` to you:

```
sudo chown username:username /usr/bin/sublime
sudo chown -R username:username /home/username/.config/sublime-text-3/
```

Replace `username` with your actual username.

Now, you should be able to run sublime by just:

```
sublime
```

Answer (score 0):

Sublime stores packages in a directory which is not writable by users  (`/opt/sublime_text`). Therefore, you can only update the packages using sudo / root.

Comment: Perfect answer to the question....  The question was "why?" not "How to solve this?", so upvoted!  **;-)**