# Unable to get sublime 3 to work in ubuntu terminal

Tags: 14.04, sublime-text

I have followed the instruction(For Sublime-Text-3:) on below URL to install sublime: [How do I install Sublime Text 2/3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3)

When I tried to run sublime by typing 'subl' in the terminal, nothing happens, just a new prompt.  I am using 'putty' to ssh into a VM where Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS  is installed. Anyone knows how to get sublime to work since I haven't found a working solution for the pass 3 hours googling?

Comment: Sublime Text is a GUI program that would require X forwarding with SSH to access remotely (and I'm honestly not sure how that would work with Windows). Are you able to run other GUI programs, such as Gedit, on the server through putty/SHH?

Comment: http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xforwarding.shtml