# Stuck at the spinning Ubuntu logo

Tags: boot, lightdm

I'm stuck on boot with the spinny Ubuntu logo never stopping.

I just started a new job and was given an existing HP with Ubuntu Studio 17 on it. I was rolling along on it just fine until I decided I wanted to try out the Sublime Text editor, which requires the root user, which the machine wasn't set up for.

I had some success getting root enabled, but it still wasn't allowing me to get Sublime installed, so I looked around for some more hints, and The Last Thing I did was follow these instructions: http://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/enable-ubuntu-desktop-root-login/

... which ends with editing /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf with

```
[SeatDefaults]    
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

...saved that and rebooted. Can't get past the spinny ubuntu start up screen now.

I finally booted from a Live CD and edited the above changes out, but the computer is still stuck in spinny logo purgatory. Obviously something else needs to be changed, updated, hacked and/or deleted. I've looked all over for clues on how to get around this without any success.

Any clues I can use?

Comment: Log in through the terminal (ctrl+alt+F1) What is the output of *ls /usr/share/xgreeters*

Comment: ctrl+alt+f1 does something really odd. Now there's a large blinking underscore cursor mark in the upper left like you'd imagine from a terminal, but in the center of the screen there's a small square that still shows the center of the spinny logo, still spinning. It does not seem to respond to the keyboard. :-(

Answer (score 2):

You should not enable the root user on ubuntu, use sudo instead.
If you boot into ubuntu, and get to the spinning ubuntu startup screen, press esc
to see the bootmessages. what are those saying?
Also what instructions did you follow to install sublime text editor? It seems really strange that you are required to use the root user for this.
look at these instructions for installing sublime: [How do I install Sublime Text 2/3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3)
I also believe Seatdefaults should be SetDefaults, maybe it would help removing that file and reconfiguring lightdm?
If you're stuck at the spinny logo, try ctrl+alt+f1 to open a terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

don't log in as root to do this, but as your own useraccount.
for more info on lightdm, read this wiki:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Comment: I'm afraid it's been more than a week, so I don't remember where I got the sublime instructions.  On boot, the machine doesn't respond to the escape key.  ctrl+alt+f1 does something really odd.  Now there's a large blinking underscore cursor mark in the upper left like you'd imagine from a terminal, but in the center of the screen there's a small square that *still shows* the center of the spinny logo, still spinning.  

It does not seem to respond to the keyboard.  :-(

Comment: try to reboot to a different runlevel then, and try from there. 
Reboot into grub, and press e. you can enter configuration options for starting then. if you add a 3 to the end of the linux line, it should boot in runlevel 3 (without GUI) then you should be able to run the command and reboot again

Comment: Added the "3", booted.  The spinny logo appeared, then the spinny part went away.  I hit ctrl+alt+f1 and got the text terminal and was able to get into my account!

sudo tail -10 /var/log/lightdm.log

shows:

Comment: `failed to find session configuration unity-greeter`
`failed to create greeter session`
`failed to start seat: seat0`

... now off to do more googling on how to turn this frown upside down!

Comment: ran 
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
which returned no errors or messages

Comment: `sudo start lightdm`
says `sudo: start: command not found`
... a new mystery...

Comment: try init 5 , or ctrl alt f7

Comment: Tried `startx`on the command line, and lightdm fired right up! Ok, so I have use of the box again! That's a welcome improvement.  On reboot still have to run thru that process to get the GUI going, but in the morning I can tackle that set of issues.

Comment: Ok, so now we know the x server is not starting up properly.. at least that's a step forward :)

Comment: @stumblebee output of `ls /usr/share/xgreeters` is `lightdm-greeter.desktop lighted-gtk-greeter.desktop`

Comment: Looks like the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` command did this:
`[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-show-manual-login=true`

When left to it's own devices, the machine still spins the logo forever on boot.  Not sure how to move forward debugging this.  By jumping through the hoops above, I can get in and use the machine.  Not so much for the non-technical people around here.

Comment: it seems weird that that command did that, since there's a typo in it. can you just remove the config file and run that again,

Comment: There's a typo in here?  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: no, [SeatDefaults] is supposed to be [SetDefaults]

Comment: Ugh!  I completely missed that.  In the meantime I gave up and re-installed from scratch.

Comment: that's not a bad idea. mostly it's better to not manually reconfigure packages, except if you have some sort of gui for it. especially if you've been messing with the root user, reïnstallation is probably the best option