# sublime text does not open

Tags: c, sublime-text

I've installed sublime text 3 using the [instructions from this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3/227617), but after doing `subl` it doesn't open anything.... I am trying to open C files.

It doesn't do anything:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you click the Sublime icon at the bottom (3rd from right)?

Answer (score 2):

Problem
Same as above. After installing sublime, it would not launch.

I tried this solution and it worked

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0
```

in Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: The same worked for me in Ubuntu: 18.04. Thanks man!

Comment: Same for 20.04, thank you!